# Items are directly added in overflow menu in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-actionbaractivity

I'm developing an application in which i need to show a button with an icon on action bar. I tried following but it directly adds in overflow menu. I want it on action bar.

I tried a few solution given here on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. please tell me what i'm missing

here is xml file of menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/action_wishlist"
      android:icon="@drawable/wish"
      android:title="WishList"
      android:orderInCategory="0"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</menu>
```

it Adds item named 'Wishlist' in overflow menu.

Theme i'm using is

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

thanks.

Comment: have you tried the value "always" for the "showAsAction" attribute ?

Comment: yes. i have. in fact there's lots of room available on actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Theme.Holo.Light`, that means that you are not using `appcompat-v7` for the action bar, but instead you are using the native action bar. In that case, change `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: now button is there on actionbar but without icon. in fact button is invisible. if i touch on it, it'll redirect to new activity but icon is not displaying. any ideas?

Comment: @Apsaliya: Perhaps there is an issue with the drawable resource you are using for the icon. You might also get rid of `orderInCategory`, as you are not really using it, though I would not expect it to address your missing-icon issue.

Comment: you are right. no need of orderInCategory. I checked with 2-3 different icons but the problem is same in all the cases.

Comment: @Apsaliya: Sorry, but there is nothing I can really do for you about that.

Comment: hi @CommonsWare again. I changed theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light and then changed xmlns in menu. Everything worked normally. Thanks for your comments.